# $G$-structure defined by a tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, tensors, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Let $M$ be an $n$ dimensional manifold with its bundle of linear frames $\pi:L(M)\to M$. Suppose $T_0$ is a tensor on $\mathbb R^n$ and $u\in L(M)$. We may view $u$ as a linear map $u:\mathbb R^n\to T_{\pi(u)}M$. Obtain the induced morphism of tensor algebras $u_*:\mathfrak T(\mathbb R^n)\to\mathfrak T(T_{\pi(u)}M)$.

How may we view $T=u_*T_0$ as a section of $\mathfrak T(M)$, when $T$ is only a tensor above $\pi(u)$?

Now let $G<GL(n,\mathbb R)$ be the largest Lie subgroup that leaves $T_0$ invariant. How can we use invariance of $T_0$ to define a section of the associated bundle $L(M)/G$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How may we view $T=u_∗T_0$ as a section of $T(M)$, when T is only a tensor above $π(u)$?

We can't. Hovever by changing $u$ in $L(M)$ we can. In case of $G$ structure wehere $G$ is a group of transformations leaving $T_0$ untached wewill get a tensor on $M$. Which leads to the answear to the second question.

> Now let $G<GL(n,R)$ be the largest Lie subgroup that leaves $T_0$ invariant. How can we use invariance of $T_0$ to define a section of the associated bundle $L(M)/G$?

Namely we have a corespondance between $G$ structures and tensor fields $0$-reductible to $T_0$. When having $G$ structure $P \subset L(M)$ we define $$T_x={u_x}_* T_0$$ when $u_x \in P_x$ and the definition is correct since any two $u_x$'s in $P_x$ differ by an element of $G$. When having $T$ we simply define $$ P_x = \left\{ u_x \in L(M)_x :{u_x}_*T_0=T_x   \right\} .$$

Comment: What does 0-reductible mean?

Comment: Precisely that $T_x={u_x}_* T_0$ for some frame at every point $x \in M$, i.e. that the tensor can in some frame be written as $T_0$ if you identify the frame members with the canonical basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Ok thank you! Is this terminology standard? I have never heard it! What does the $0$ stand for in $0$-reductible?

Comment: Nowadays it may be a little old fashioned to use this terminology but it is standard. It refers to the level of integrability of a geometric structure. You can read on it in Kobayashi's Transformation groups or Goldberg's notes.

Comment: @J.E.M.S probably you'd know how to answer also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4435031/holonomy-of-g-structure-fixed-by-tensor-fields) question