# Tensor fields defining $G$-structure are parallel

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, connections, principal-bundles, holonomy

Suppose $G \leq GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the stabilizer of some tensors $T^0_1, ..., T^0_k$, let $P$ be a $G$-structure on a manifold, i.e. a principal $G$ subbundle of the frame bundle of $M$ and let $T_1, ..., T_k$ be tensor fields that are pointwise the image of $T^0_1, ..., T^0_k$ through the frames of $P$, as in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361952/g-structure-defined-by-a-tensor) question.
Is it true that the tensor fields $T_1, ..., T_k$ are parallel with respect to any given connection on $P$? If you want add the hypothesis of the connection on $P$ being torsion-free (meaning the induced connection on the tangent bundle is) but I believe this is not needed.
Alternatively, is it true that if the holonomy of a Riemannian manifold is contained in $G$ then the tensors defining (in the sense of the linked question) the $G$ structure are parallel? By looking at Berger's classification it looks true.

I guess that one way to go would be to argue that the parallel transport of a generic tensor on $M$ is characterized by the principal bundle this way: take a tensor at a point, pull it back through a frame at that point getting a tensor on $\mathbb{R}^n$, transport the frame to the point you want and finally push forward the tensor through the new frame.
However I am not at all familiar with parallel transport on induced vector bundles to argue that this is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, then tensor fields are indeed parallel and this is independent of torsion-freeness.
In fact, if you take any $G$-invariant tensor $T_0\in\otimes^k\mathbb R^{n*}\otimes\otimes^\ell\mathbb R^n$, this gives rise to a $\binom\ell k$-tensor field $T$ on any manifold $M$ endowed with a $G$-structure $P$ by "pulling back along the frames in $P$".
Now you can view the tensor bundle $\otimes^k T^*M\otimes\otimes^\ell TM$ as the associated bundle $P\times_G(\otimes^k\mathbb R^{n*}\otimes\otimes^\ell\mathbb R^n)$ and correspondingly, $\binom\ell k$-tensor fields on $M$ are in bijective correspondence with $G$-equivariant smooth functions $P\to \otimes^k\mathbb R^{n*}\otimes\otimes^\ell\mathbb R^n$. By construction, in this picture $T$ corresponds to the constant function $T_0$.
But for any principal connection $\gamma$ on $P$ the induced connection $\nabla$ on $\binom\ell k$-tensor fields has the property that for a vector field $\xi\in\mathfrak X(M)$ the equivariant function corresponding to $\nabla_\xi T$ is obtained by differentiating the equivariant function corresponding to $T$ with respect to the horizontal lift of $\xi$ to $P$.
But of course, if you differentiate a constant function, you always get $0$.

Comment: Ok this is very elegant. I guess the property you mention is theorem 19.5 from Michor's differential geometry. What reference did you know this property from? Or you just guessed it? I did not reach the stage yet of guessing this kind of things for this topic, but hopefully that'll happen soon

Comment: @JackFres I do not want to talk for Andreas Cap, I just want to help.  In my opinion a very good book focused on this matter is Simon Salamon's Riemannian geometry and holonomy groups. 
Other two books where you can find these things are Joyce's  Riemannian Holonomy Groups and Calibrated Geometry and also Besse's Einstein manifolds (Besse is a pseudonym and one of the authors in reality is Berger).

Comment: This is a matter of principal bundle / associated bundle theory. You are right, you can get it from 19.5 of Michors book, but it is not so easily visible there, things things are immediately done in a more general setting. For me, this is the way how I define induced connections on associated bundles. This explains an motivates all the properties that one requires from a principal connection and it makes  several other (e.g. functorial) properties very transparent. If you need a reference, you can use Prop. 1.3.4 of my joint book MR2532439 with J. Slovak.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot to both for the reference suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

**Remark1.** Recall that the holonomy of a metric is the holonomy of its Levi-Civita connection. Thus a manifold may admit an affine connection with holonomy in $G<GL(n)$ and still not admitting any metric with holonomy in $G$.

**Remark2.** If there is a reduction of the structure group to $G<GL(n)$, then there is a connection with holonomy $G$. This is essentially the fact that any vector bundle admits a connection applied to the vector bundle induced by the reduction.

**Prop1.** *Exists an $n$-manifolds $X$ and subgroup $G<GL(n), G = Stab(T)$ ($T$ in the tensor algebra of $\mathbb R^n$) such that the frame bundle of $X$ admits a reduction of the structure group to $G$ but $X$ does not admit a metric with holonomy in $G$. In particular there is no Riemannian connection on $TX$ which is torsion free and for which the tensor induced by $G$ is parallel.*

*proof:*
For example, an almost Hermitian manifold is a manifold with an almost complex structure $J$ and a compatible Riemannian metric $g$.
The pair $(J,g)$ exists iff there is a reduction of the structure group to $U(2n)$. This condition is homotopy-theoretical in nature. Indeed by a theorem of Wu, we know that in dimension 4 such a structure exists iff the third integral Stiefel-Whitney class $W_3\in H^3(X,\mathbb Z)$ and $c^2-2\chi(M)-3\sigma(X)\in H^4(X,\mathbb Z)$ vanish ($c$ is the first Chern-class of $J$).
However the existence of a torsion free connection for which $(J,g)$ is parallel would imply that the Nijenhuis tensor vanishes and hence $X$ would be a complex manifold with $J$ as induced ACS. This is not true in general.
For example $\mathbb{CP}^2\#\mathbb{CP}^2\#\mathbb{CP}^2$ admits an ACS but not a a complex structure  (a proof that uses the Bogomolov-Miyaoka-Yau may be found in [these notes by Aleksandar Milivojević](https://guests.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/milivojevic/acsbutnotcx.pdf)).

**Prop2.** *Let $G = \bigcap_i Stab(T_i^0)< GL(n)$, $T_i^0$ in the tensor algebra of $\mathbb R^n$ and  suppose that $X$ has a reduction to of the structure group to $G$ with associated $G$-principal bundle $P\to X$. Let $\nabla$ be a connection on $P$. Then the induced tensor fields $T_i$ obtained from $T^0_i$ are $\nabla$-parallel.*

*Proof:* Since $\nabla$ is a connection  $P$ it has holonomy contained in $G$.
The tensors $T_i$ associated to the reduction are obtained by parallel transporting the model $T^0_1, \dots, T^0_k$ written in a G-frame given by the reduction.
The holonomy contained in $G = Stab(T^0_k)$  ensures that this procedure yields well defined tensors $T_i$.

*EDIT after comment.*
Consider a frame $F_{x_0}$ at $x_0 \in X$ in the reduction $G_{x_0}$ and consider a tensor $T_{i,x_0}$ at $x_0$ that has components equal to  $T^0_i$ in this frame.
Now define a tensor field $T_i$ by parallel transporting $T_{i,x_0}$.
Consider a point $x\in X$. Then, since $T_i$ is defined by parallel transport,   $T_i(x)$ will have components equal to $T^0_i$ in any frame obtained by  parallel transporting $F_{x_0}$ to $x$ along any curve $\gamma$ joining $x_0$ to $x$.
But since $G$ stabilizes $T^0_i$, if we represent $T_i(x)$ in any other frame in $G_x$ we will obtain the same components $T^0_i$.

Therefore the two definitions coincide.

Comment: Sorry, my question was ambiguous, I will edit it immediately. I meant that the existence of a torsion-free connection is part of the hypotheses (equivalently the $G$-structure is torsion-free) and then I ask if it is true that the tensors are parallel with respect to any such connection. I put torsion-free in parentheses because I believe torsion-free is not necessary.

Comment: As for the second part I was wondering if the tensors $T_1, ..., T_k$ I started with are parallel. Your argument would answer my question if you can also prove that the tensor you obtain by parallel transport are equal to the ones defining the $G$-structure that I started with.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the edit! Maybe I am misinterpreting your argument, but is it any different from the argument I suggested at the last part of my answer? If it is the same thing, which I suspect, what I was missing is to prove that parallel transporting a tensor or parallel transporting a frame and then pushing forward the tensor are the same thing. In your answer the part I cannot justify basically is why "$T_i(x)$ will have components equal to $T^0_i$ in any frame obtained by parallel transporting $F_{x_0}$". Can you say a word on that?

Comment: Moreover, you agree that at this point the answer is positive to both parts of the question right?

Comment: @JackFres parallel transporting a frame along a curve $\gamma : [0,1]\to X $ establishes a *linear isomorphism* between the fiber at $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma(1)$. Once you know how a frame is transported, you know how any vector is transported.

Comment: The answer to the first question is no, what I showed with my counter example is that exists a 4-manifold that has a $U(2)$-structure but the tensors $(J,g)$ cannot be parallel for a torsion-free connection (i.e. for the Levi-Civita connection induced by $g$).

The counter example would fall if we drop the assumption that the connection is the Levi-Civita one.

Comment: But how do you know that in your example the Levi-Civita connection descends to the $U(2)$-structure $P$? I would guess that it does not otherwise the structure would be torsion-free and $J$ would be integrable... However in my question, the connection is on $P$.

Comment: As for the your other comment I agree with the intuition you provided, but I was hoping for a more formal proof of the mentioned fact that I am missing!

Comment: I see what you mean, then the answer is yes, is the proof of the second point.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to be proven more formally? The only thing left is that parallel transport establishes an isomorphism of the fiber over the endpoints of the curve. This fact may be found in any book of differential geometry defining parallel transport. The proof I gave is practically a corollary of the definitions.